# Writing a Android System app that uses KeyEvents to insert text into a text field. But Extended unicode characters are not printable

Tags: android, android-source, keyevent

So I could use a combination of CTL+ for control characters , SHIFT+  for Upper case letters like A ,B  and  characters like !,{ (i.e Basic Latin and punctuation characters) .

However I am not able to find the combination  in Android for symbols like Ã,ǆ ... etc.
Ubuntu Uses a combination of CTRL+SHIFT+U .. followed by four numbers that generate the symbol, but that does not seem translatable to Android.

TL;DR : How to generate special symbols using Android KeyEvents and KeyCharacter Map?

Update : Learnt about this  resource : https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-character-map-files  and it looks like I will have to use a key combo  and they talk about a magic hex input , but I have tried using

1111 followed by Alt+Shift+X ( qwerty.kcm file contains this) ... But it does not type out the unicode symbol to the corresponding 1111.

Can someone help with this please ?

Comment: Do you just need to inject some text/chars that you already know ( and can be hardcoded to app )? If so, you can inject chars directly like "adb shell input text" does (not keycode combinations). See how that's done here: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/cmds/input/src/com/android/commands/input/Input.java;l=149?q=%20Input.java&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject

Comment: Unfortuantely no . It can be any of the range between 0000 to FFFF. 
Also  , this is being implemented in a service that needs to insert the characters in any field that has the focus regardless of the which app it is .

Comment: See https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard seems to handle emoji by using their unicode value. 
For demo of it see https://www.cnblogs.com/syw20170419/p/10709576.html ( use Google Translate )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to figure it out .

Step 1 : Update your Android OS's kcm file (most of the cases its Generic.kcm) . The example below is with the "X" button but it can be applied to any button really . Add the alt+shift behavoir and assing the magic hex code to the combination of alt+shift+X.

```
key X {
    label:                              'X'
    base:                               'x'
    shift, capslock:                    'X'
    alt+shift:                          '\uef00'
}
```

Step 2:
Generate Keyevents for 1,2,3,4 followed by a keyevent for Alt+Shift+X  in your applications service and you will be able to print the character "ሴ" .

Read these Resources for further information.

```
https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-character-map-files
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/how-to-insert-unicode-characters-by-their-hex-codes-using-usb-keyboard-on-ics
```